# (R) Edit Gradient Color of Cells Behind Multiple Columns of Data In Data Table

Tags: r, colors, gradient, dt

I asked a similar question a few days ago and have made some progress by talking with some people, but I need a little more help to get this to the point I wanted.  So here's where I am:

I want to have a data table of a certain size with columns of data (different scales) and be able to apply a color range (kind of like a heat map) to the values in the cells of the data table depending on how large or small the values in the columns are.

Here is some code that was provided to me:

```
library(DT)
testrun <- round(runif(100), 6)

data <- data.frame(testrun = testrun)
brks <- quantile(data$testrun, probs = seq(.05, .95, .01), na.rm = TRUE) 

clrs_df <- colorRamp(c("white","blue"))(c(0,brks))  %>%
  as_tibble(.name_repair ="minimal") %>%
  setNames(nm=c("r","g","b")) %>%
  mutate_all(~as.character(round(.,digits=0)))  %>%
 mutate(mycolor=paste0("rgb(",paste(r,g,b,sep = ","),")"))

 clrs <- pull(clrs_df,mycolor)
 DT::datatable(data,rownames=TRUE,options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t')) %>%
      formatStyle(colnames(data), backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

The above example works for one column of data, but I intend to have multiple columns of data for which I want these color gradients to apply to each column individually.

I've tried substituting mtcars for testrun in the assignment portion of the code and in the brks assignment line, but it just leaves me with a table with no colors applied.

Can someone help point me in the right direction?  Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
library(DT)
data <- data.frame(
  C1 = rnorm(100),
  C2 = rgamma(100, 10, 10)
)

dtable <- datatable(data, rownames=TRUE, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, dom='t'))

colRamp <- colorRamp(c("white","blue"))
for(column in names(data)){
  x <- na.omit(data[[column]])
  brks <- quantile(x, probs = seq(.05, .95, .01))
  RGB <- colRamp(c(0, (brks-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))))
  clrs <- apply(RGB, 1, function(rgb){
    sprintf("rgb(%s)", toString(round(rgb,0)))
  })
  dtable <- dtable %>% 
    formatStyle(column, backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
}

dtable
```